# How to plot a chart with data from another file

Tags: arrays, swift

I am plotting 2 Graphs in my ViewController and want to plot another Graph in another ViewController(Events) using the data from my Matrix saved in ViewController.

Somehow my code does work when I run it in my ViewController.
But if I run it in Events.swift is says "no Chart Data available"

```
func matrixChart(index: Int, values: [[Double]]){ 

        lineChartView.clearValues()
        var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []

        for i in 0..<values.count{
            for j in 0..<values[i].count{
            let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(x: values[0][j], y: Double(i)) 
            dataEntries.append(dataEntry) }
        }
        lineChartDataSet2 = LineChartDataSet(entries: dataEntries, label: nil)
        colors.append(UIColor.green)
        lineChartDataSet2.colors = colors
        lineChartDataSet2.circleRadius = 0.5
        _ = LineChartData(dataSet: lineChartDataSet2)
        self.lineChartView.data = lineChartData2
    }
```

UPDATE:

I pass my data by using a method from Events.swift in Eventcounter.swift:

```
let e = Events()
e.matrixChart(index: index, values: matrix)
```

and use parameters from Eventcounter.swift

Comment: And how are you passing data between the view controllers?

Comment: `no Chart Data available` means `dataEntries` list is empty. So probably its a data passing issue between `viewControllers`